# Pass the array index to component using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How do you pass the index number ?

```
arrayOfObj = [ {},{},{} ] 

{this.arrayOfObj.map(user => (
    <Comp index={user.index}/>
))}
```

Output should be

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: `.map` second parameter is the index, so `.map((user, i) => ...` `i` is the index

Comment: Map technically has 3 passed in properties, you just use 1 of them.  `item, index, array`

Comment: you "never", need the third property with map

Comment: @EugenSunic I just used the third property within the past week or less,(albeit not in a React context)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second parameter of the `map` is the index. You can do it like:

```
arrayOfObj = [{},{},{}] 

{this.arrayOfObj.map((user, index) => (
    return <Comp index={index}/>
))}
```

You can read more about `map` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I think that you should explain all 3 properties which are passed in. People forget there are 3.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Thanks for that. Just added a link to documentation.

Comment: awesome thx everyone